# How can we use batch processing in ETL?

Tags: etl

Can anyone tell me how to leverage batch processing in ETL? I have been working in ETL and testing for a year now but haven't used batch processing. Can anyone guide me to any nice read or a small educational and introductory writing would also be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Refer below link, you will get some ideas

https://www.talend.com/resources/batch-processing/